# Need help on converting free english text to Kusto query

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I need help on the below free text that should be converted to Kusto query..

### Free text:

1 event within 1 second

And

```
 /All Filters/Device Product Specific/Microsoft/All Microsoft Windows Events

 /All Filters/Content Development/Device Product Specific/Microsoft/Windows/Windows All/System and Service Changes/All - Windows Event or Audit Log was Cleared
```

Not

```
  /All Filters/Content Development/1 - Testing/DH/Process Failure/Windows Audit Log Cleared/Filter Out/Windows Audit Log Cleared
```

/All Filters/Content Development/Device Product Specific/Microsoft/Windows/Windows All/System and Service Changes/All - Windows Event or Audit Log was Cleared

Or

( "/All Filters/Device Product Specific/Microsoft/Windows 2008/System and Service Changes/Windows Audit Log was Cleared" )

Or

( "/All Filters/Device Product Specific/Microsoft/Windows 2003/System and Service Changes/Windows Audit or Event Log was Cleared" )

Or

( "/All Filters/Device Product Specific/Microsoft/Windows 2008/System and Service Changes/Windows Event Log was Cleared" ) )

/All Filters/Device Product Specific/Microsoft/Windows 2008/System and Service Changes/Windows Audit Log was Cleared

deviceEventClassId EQ "Microsoft-Windows-Eventlog:517"

/All Filters/Device Product Specific/Microsoft/Windows 2008/System and Service Changes/Windows Event Log was Cleared

deviceEventClassId EQ "Microsoft-Windows-Eventlog:1102"

/All Filters/Device Product Specific/Microsoft/Windows 2003/System and Service Changes/Windows Audit or Event Log was Cleared

deviceEventClassId EQ "Microsoft-Windows-Eventlog:104"

/All Filters/Content Development/1 - Testing/DH/Process Failure/Windows Audit Log Cleared/Filter Out/Windows Audit Log Cleared (list of host names to be excluded)

“XADMA10x.GD.LDAP", "XADMA11x.GD.LDAP", "XADMA12x.GD.LDAP", "XADMA13x.GD.LDAP", "XADMA14x.GD.LDAP", "XADMA14x.GD.LDAP", "XADMA15x.GD.LDAP"

Comment: Can you provide a sample data in the shape of table, describe the queries and ideally provide the expected output?

Comment: @Avnera default table shape, data and everything is default . There is no specific structure.  The working space: https://portal.loganalytics.io/demo

Comment: The expected output: Vendor || Product || EentID || Hostname

Comment: Sorry Raj - can you provide the initial query? Every query in Kusto starts with a tabular dataset or tabular operator such as "search", in the workspace you sent there are many tables. Can you send a starter query to improve?

Comment: Hi Avnera, There is no query and got this free text only. We are asked to convert this free text to corresponding KQL.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand.